# Groovy Concept of Closure

Tags: groovy, closures

I'm a bit confused as to the term "closure" used within the Groovy [documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html). According to the documentation, their definition of a closure seems more like an anonymous function or lambda.

I understand that languages that support first class functions, typically allow closures to be formed.  However, there is a distinction between the two concepts.

For example, according to the Groovy docs:

> A closure in Groovy is an anonymous
>   chunk of code that may take arguments,
>   return a value, and reference and use
>   variables declared in its surrounding
>   scope.
>
> In functional language parlance, such an anonymous code block might be referred to as an anonymous lambda expression in general or lambda expression with unbound variables or a closed lambda expression if it didn't contain references to unbound variables (like threshold in the earlier example). Groovy makes no such distinction.

Then according to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) page on Closures:

> The term closure is often mistakenly used to mean anonymous function.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it says in the next paragraph of the same [page you linked to in the groovy docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures+-+Formal+Definition):

> Strictly speaking, a closure can't be
>   defined. You can define a block of
>   code that refers to local variables or
>   fields/properties, but it becomes a
>   closure only when you "bind" (give it
>   a meaning) this block of code to
>   variables. The closure is a semantic
>   concept, like an instance, which you
>   cannot define, just create. Strictly
>   spoken a closure is only a closure if
>   all free variables are bound. Unless
>   this happens it is only partially
>   closed, hence not really a closure.
>   Since Groovy doesn't provide a way to
>   define a closed lambda function and a
>   block of code might not be a closed
>   lambda function at all (because it has
>   free variables), we refer to both as
>   closure - even as syntactic concept.
>   We are talking about it as syntactic
>   concept, because the code of defining
>   and creating an instance is one, there
>   is no difference. We very well know
>   that this terminology is more or less
>   wrong, but it simplifies many things
>   when talking about code in a language
>   that doesn't "know" the difference.

Comment: It's probably the last sentence `We very well know that this terminology is more or less wrong, but it simplifies many things when talking about code in a language that doesn't "know" the difference.` that explains it best ;-)

Comment: That part is clear. However, it is the stuff before that caused my brain to mentally give up, and skip over the entire paragraph. :)

Comment: This paragraph is completely missing in the tutorials. I did search for this clarification for hours. Thx!